# Fontawesome icons not showing up on my clients' mobile devices, can't replicate

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, icons, font-awesome

I have an expandable menu that uses fontawesome arrows. It's working on all browsers on desktop, and it's working on my iPhone, but my clients aren't seeing the arrows. They tested on Android, iPad, and MS Surface Pro. I asked them to try tapping the area where the icons are supposed to be to see if the menu still expands and the icons are just invisible, but the menus aren't expanding either.

[Screenshot from my iPhone, where it's working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4sQn.png)

[Screenshot my client sent me from her Android phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UqDl.png)

Because the menus aren't expanding at all, I wonder if it's a javascript problem? But it works everywhere but on mobile devices?

This is the code to expand/retract the menus

```
function expandMenu(button) {
    var childMenu = $(button).parent().find("ul");
    var hideMenu = $(button).parent().find("a.hide-second-level");
    $(button).hide();
    hideMenu.show();
    $(childMenu).show();
}

function retractMenu(button) {
    var childMenu = $(button).parent().find("ul");
    var showMenu = $(button).parent().find("a.show-second-level");
    $(button).hide();
    showMenu.show();
    $(childMenu).hide();
}
```

the links:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expandMenu($(this))" class="show-second-level toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="retractMenu($(this))" class="hide-second-level toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I experienced this once. There was an issue with some icons in the FA. Have you tried different icon just for test?